# What is the difference between blog.title and blog[title]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Assume blog is my object/array. Is one defined for objects and one for arrays? What is the fundamental difference between them and where do I use which one?

Comment: There's a big difference between `blog.title` and `blog[title]`. One gets the `title` property of the object `blog`. The other gets the `undefined` property of the object `title`, unless the `title` variable is defined beforehand.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Can you be more specific? Which one gets the title property and which one gets the undefined property?

Comment: The first gets the `title` property. But read the answers to the duplicate -- they go into much more detail.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!